# How do I shuffle the first two dimensions of this 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pygame

I am working on a program where I want to display a picture and randomize the pixels (then, hopefully sort them back into place). I found a tutorial that uses an array3d to load an image as pixels into a 3D array (rows, columns, RGB values). numpy.random.shuffle() only shuffles the top dimension. Is there an easy way to shuffle both the rows and columns as if they were in the same dimension (without tampering with the third dimension, the color values)?

```py
import pygame
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

image = pygame.image.load('smiley.png')
# The pixels we will manipulate.
pixels = pygame.surfarray.array3d(image)

# Set up window
w, h = pixels.shape[0], pixels.shape[1]
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

while True:
    # Draw array onto screen
    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(display_surface, pixels)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                # Scramble the pixels
                np.random.shuffle(pixels)

        pygame.display.update()
```

I can iterate through each row and scramble those on their own, but realistically I'd want to shuffle each x,y pixel as if they were the same array. I am a beginner with numpy. Could I transpose the 3D array into a 2D one, shuffle it, and transpose back into a 3D array? Am I overthinking this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
np.random.shuffle(pixels)
np.random.shuffle(np.swapaxes(pixels, 0, 1))
```

?  Shuffle is in-place and swapaxes returns a view, so it should function as you describe.

Comment: same result than mine, but probably more efficient :D

Comment: This looks pretty good. It still creates an odd grid-like pattern to the pixels, but is much closer to what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you will still end up with as you mention, a grid-like pattern, if you do it as described.  Humans are good at detecting this stuff =).  This is because shuffling one axis at a time only gives you `w!h!` possible outcomes, instead of `(wh)!`, which is a rather huge reduction.

Answer (score 0):

When I understood you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# create an 3x3 array like your picture:
pixels= np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))

# shuffle dimension 2:
for i in range(0, pixels.shape[0]):
    np.random.shuffle(pixels[i][:])
    pixels= pixels.copy()

# shuffle dimension 1:
np.random.shuffle(pixels[:])

# output:
pixels
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a secondary answer so you can choose.  I believe this one may be slower (but actually is random among all coordinates).

```
np.random.shuffle(np.reshape(pixels, -1))
```

If for some reason it is a new object instead of a view, you will have to do something like

```
pixels = np.reshape(np.random.shuffle(np.reshape(pixels, -1)), (w, h, -1))
```

instead.